# Folland 8.20 (Fourier Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm stuck a bit on this problem from Folland:

[image]

The first part I can't figure out at all.

The second part, I know: $\|Pf(x)\|_1 = |Pf(x)| = |\int f(x,y)dy| \leq \int |f(x,y)|dy$. If the last term is finite, I'm done. It should be finite since $f \in \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, but I think I'm missing a step.

For the third part:

$\widehat{Pf}(\xi) = \int Pf(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dx = \int \int f(x,y) e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dy dx $

$\hat{f}(\xi, 0) = \int f(x,0)e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dx$

But I don't see anyway to make these two expressions equal each other.

Comment: As regards the second part, $||Pf(x)||_1=\int |\int f(x,y)\,dy|\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation of the $L^1$ norm is incorrect. Since $$\|Pf\|_1 = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |Pf(x)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left| \int_{\mathbb R^m} f(x,y) \, dy \right| \, dx \le \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^m} |f(x,y)| \, dy  \, dx = \|f\|_1$$ you get $Pf \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and the desired inequality. As for the Fourier transform, your formula is incorrect. The proper formulation is
$$ \hat f(\xi,\eta) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^m} f(x,y) e^{-2\pi i (\xi \cdot x + \eta \cdot y)}\, dy \, dx$$
so that
$$ \hat f(\xi,0) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^m} f(x,y) e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot x}\, dy \, dx.$$

Comment: Maybe mention Fubini?

Comment: Ah, thank you. The problem is much easier when I can actually get the formulations correct